# Distributing Python programs with a Tkinter GUI using pysintaller

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I've been distributing my program to my users but the font doesn't stay the same in the Tkinter GUI.

I've been compiling with pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe as a onefile meaning theres only an executable.

How can I compile with the font libraries? Am I missing something or is it the wrong setting in the pyinstaller?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a .spec file? and if so are all external resources, including the fonts located in the same folder as the .spec?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter not really sure. Before I compile I’ve just got a .py file. There are some folders but they don’t interfere with the font. I’m using fonts from Tkinter, specifically ‘Dubai Light’. The code in the .pay file is literally just: ‘font=“Dubai Light”’

Comment: The font is not part of tkinter, it is part of your OS.  So better use some common font across systems.

Comment: @acw1668 is there a list of common fonts that I could choose from :)

Comment: Arial, Courier, Helvetica, Times, etc.

Comment: You can try using `pyglet` module to load a TTF font file to be used in the tkinter application, then you can embed the font file together with the tkinter application into the executable.  But make sure you have the right to distribute the font file.